# How could I let Eclipse export my configuration file and place it along with my executable?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I need to export my configuration file and place it along with my executable while exporting a RCP product. The configration file in log4j.properties which is situated inside `EditorAPP` RCP application.
For that purpose, I have created Feature Project `FeatureTreeEditor` and inside it there is a feature.xml and build properties.
The build.properties looks like this:

```
bin.includes = feature.xml
root=file:log4j.properties
```

The feature.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="FeatureTreeEditor"
      label="FeatureTreeEditor"
      version="1.0.0.qualifier">

   <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
      [Enter Feature Description here.]
   </description>

   <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
      [Enter Copyright Description here.]
   </copyright>

   <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
      [Enter License Description here.]
   </license>

   <plugin
         id="EditorApp"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

IN my RCP plugin project (`EditorApp`, which is a simple RCP plugin project), I have created a new product - `newProduct.product` . This product is feature based. In product definition , I have chosen `EditorApp.application`.
 In the dependencies tab, I have added the feature `FeatureTreeEditor`.

Then, I am exporting the product. I have found now after adding the feature project in RCP project, now, after exporting a folder named `features` is getting generated. But, I am not able to find log4j.properties anywhere.

Do I need to modify my existing old RCP Application in some way?

Please help!

Comment: Where have you put the log4j.properties file? It must be in the root directory of the feature project for this to work.

Comment: Just found out !! Thanks again!